# ajax() loses form data on submission

Tags: jquery, forms

i have a contact for which uses jquery ajax() to submit the form data. It works on xampp but on the server, the form data that is supposed to be sent to the php file becomes blank. nothing at all is sent to the external file

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("input#regbut").click(function(){
          var edin = $("input[name^='name']").val();
      var mailer = $("input[name^='email']").val();
      var dept = $("input:radio[name^='direct']:checked").val();
      var hint = $("input[name^='subject']").val();
      var bodied = $("textarea[name^='message']").val();
      var seri = "name=" + edin + "&email=" + mailer + "&direct=" + dept + "&subject=" + hint + "&message=" + bodied;

      $("span#war").fadeIn(function(){
         $("span#war").css("display", "block");
      });
      $("#warn").html('');
      if(edin ==''){
               $("#warn").html('You did not tell us your name');
      }else if(mailer == ''){
               $("#warn").html('Your email is required');
      }else if(hint == ''){
               $("#warn").html('Subject is required');
      }else if(bodied == ''){
               $("#warn").html('You did not tell us what the problem is');
      }else{
         $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "contactpro.php",
            data: seri,
            error: function(){
               $("#warn").html("Sorry! an error occurred");
            },
            success: function(repo){
               $("#warn").html(repo);
               alert(repo);
            }
         });
      }
      return false;
   });
});

<form method="post" id="cotact">
              <table width="80%" border="0" cellspacing="3" cellpadding="1">
                <tr>
                  <td></td>
                  <td id="warn" style="color:#FF0000;"><h3 style="color:#0099FF;"><span id="war" style="display:none;">Sending...</span></h3></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>Name</td>
                  <td><label>
                    <input name="name" type="text" class="input" id="sign_up" />
                  </label></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>Email </td>
                  <td><label>
                    <input name="email" type="text" class="input" id="sign_up" />
                  </label></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>Direct to</td>
                  <td><p>
                      <label>
                      <input name="direct" type="radio" id="direct_0" value="1" checked="checked" />
                        General</label>
                      / enquiry<br />
                      <label>
                      <input type="radio" name="direct" value="2" id="direct_1" />
                        Advertising</label>
                      <br />
                      <label>
                      <input type="radio" name="direct" value="3" id="direct_2" />
                        Reports</label>
                      <br />
                      <label>
                      <input type="radio" name="direct" value="4" id="direct_3" />
                        Suggestions</label>
                      <br />
                  </p></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>Subject</td>
                  <td><label>
                    <input name="subject" type="text" class="input" id="sign_up" />
                  </label></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>Message</td>
                  <td><label>
                    <textarea name="message" cols="45" rows="5" class="input" id="sign_up" style="height:100px;"></textarea>
                  </label></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>&nbsp;</td>
                  <td><label>
                    <input type="submit" name="submit" id="regbut" value="Submit" />
                  </label></td>
                </tr>
              </table>
          </form></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td colspan="2" align="center"></td>
        </tr>
      </table>
```

Comment: relative paths are the same?

Comment: Change `type: "GET"` to `type: "POST"` and `data: "seri"` to `data: "postDATA"`. Also, form method should be "POST", too.

Comment: Why do you use GET to send a relatively large amount of information? Moreover, it is a bad idea to construct the data like `seri = "name="+ edin + "&email=" + mailer + "&direct="` - what if one of the variables has & in it? you should escape the data or let jQuery do it for you.

Comment: Only change GET to POST & try again.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell what's going on, but try passing an object to `data` in your `$.ajax` call instead of a query string like you have, for example:

```
        ... 
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "contactpro.php",
            data: {
               name: edin,
               email: mailer,
               ...
            },
            error: function(){
               $("#warn").html("Sorry! an error occurred");
            },
            success: function(repo){
               $("#warn").html(repo);
               alert(repo);
            }
         });
         ...
```

Also, verify that you're checking `$_GET` since your ajax request specifies that request method (I notice your form method is `post`) are you certain you're not checking `$_POST`? If you want the ajax request to be send via `POST`, then change the type to `"POST"`

Answer (score 0):

It's very difficult to tell. Try make JSON and change the type to "post"

```
var seri = "name :edin,email: mailer, direct:dept, subject:hint, message:bodied}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#form").submit(function(e) {
  var postData = $(this).serializeArray();
  var formURL = $(this).attr("action");
  $.ajax( {
    url : formURL,
    type: "POST",
    data : postData,
    success:function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) 
    {
      // should it work
    },
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) 
    {
      // should something go crazy      
    }
  });
  e.preventDefault();
  e.unbind(); 
});

$("#form").submit();
```